# Show different select according to the selected option of a select

Tags: jquery

**Hello,**

I have a select with two options

```
<select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state" rel="calc_shipping_state">
    <option value="">Select a country…</option>
    <option value="IE">Republic of Ireland</option>
    <option value="GB" selected="selected">United Kingdom (UK)</option> 
</select>
```

I would like to show the following code (another select) with different options if the value of the first select is equal to UK:

```
$('#calc_shipping_state_field').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='BE'>Bedfordshire</option> <option value='BER'>Berkshire</option> <option value='BRI'>Bristol</option> <option value='BUCK'>Buckinghamshire</option> <option value='CA'>Cambridgeshire</option> <option value='CHES'>Cheshire</option> <option value='LN'>City of London</option> </select></p>");
  $( "#county_selected" ).change(function() {
    $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  });
```

And show this select if the value is equal to IE:

```
 $('#calc_shipping_state_field').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='1'>1</option> <option value='2'>2</option> <option value='3'>3</option> <option value='4'>4</option> <option value='5'>5</option> <option value='6'>6</option> <option value='7'>7</option> </select></p>");
  //     $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  //     });
```

As the first select only has two options. I thought myself I can use the following IF:

```
  $('#calc_shipping_country').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'UK'){
      $('#calc_shipping_state_field').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='BE'>Bedfordshire</option> <option value='BER'>Berkshire</option> <option value='BRI'>Bristol</option> <option value='BUCK'>Buckinghamshire</option> <option value='CA'>Cambridgeshire</option> <option value='CHES'>Cheshire</option> <option value='LN'>City of London</option> </select></p>");
      $( "#county_selected" ).change(function() {
        $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#calc_shipping_state_field').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='1'>1</option> <option value='2'>2</option> <option value='3'>3</option> <option value='4'>4</option> <option value='5'>5</option> <option value='6'>6</option> <option value='7'>7</option> </select></p>");
      $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
      });
    }
  });
```

But doesn't work...

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Could someone help me and tell me where is the mistake I'm making, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in option you have value `'GB'` whereas in if statement you are checking `if($(this).val() == 'UK')`.

Additionally, I would suggest to clear the added dynamically `select` tag using:

```
$(this).next().remove();
```

The last thing is that there is a problem with parenthesis. The correct solution:

```
 $('#calc_shipping_country').change(function(){
    $(this).next().remove();
if($(this).val() == 'GB'){
  $('#calc_shipping_country').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='BE'>Bedfordshire</option> <option value='BER'>Berkshire</option> <option value='BRI'>Bristol</option> <option value='BUCK'>Buckinghamshire</option> <option value='CA'>Cambridgeshire</option> <option value='CHES'>Cheshire</option> <option value='LN'>City of London</option> </select></p>");
  $( "#county_selected" ).change(function() {
    $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  });
}
else if($(this).val() == 'IE'){
  $('#calc_shipping_country').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='1'>1</option> <option value='2'>2</option> <option value='3'>3</option> <option value='4'>4</option> <option value='5'>5</option> <option value='6'>6</option> <option value='7'>7</option> </select></p>");
  $('#calc_shipping_state_field input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
  }
});
```

Please check [demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/e419dj0o/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help kbysiec!! Yeahh my mistake copying and pasting the values GP/UK.